# Console Logging .forEach() method

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the console to output each number in this array times 2, but it is giving me an error. Here is my code:

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const numbersForEach = numbers.forEach(timesTwo)

function timesTwo(value) {
  return value * 2;
}

console.log(numbersForEach)
```

I don't want to know if there is another way of doing this because I know there is. What I want to know is why it is not working when I do it this way.

Comment: You're looking for `.map()`, not `.forEach()`.

Comment: Your code does not produce an error.

Comment: Tangential: docs are your friend; check out some docs for [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Comment: Why do you think it *should* work when you do it that way?

Comment: Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#return_value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `forEach` method returns `undefined`. If you want to create an array based on a different array use `map`:

```
const numbersForEach = numbers.map(timesTwo);
```